# Groovy Sequence of a number

Tags: groovy

How do I get a sequence of a given number in Groovy, for example:

```
def number = 169
// need a method in groovy to find the consecutive numbers that is, 1,6,9,16,69,169
// not 19!
```

There is a method in Groovy called `subsequences()`, but that is not doing this job exactly. Can anyone say me how can I do this in Groovier way? Or is there any built-in method?

Comment: Can you explain why 19 does not belong to the list?

Comment: I suspect it is because, in the original number `169`, `1` and `9` are separated by the `6` and therefore not adjacent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although late to the game, here's a solution that is less sophisticated than @tim's, but also will do the trick:

```
def str = 169 as String
def result = [] as SortedSet
(0..<str.length()).each { i ->
    (i..<str.length()).each { j ->
        result << str[i..j].toInteger()
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

The code works like two nested loops that iterate over the String representation of the number and extracting the various substrings from it.

The outer loop represents the start index of the  substring and the inner loop the end index of the substring. The outer loop will go from the beginning to the end of the String, whereas the inner loop starts at the current start index and goes from there to the end.

The `as SortedSet` ensures that there are no duplicate numbers in the result and that the numbers are sorted in ascending order.

```
 1 6 9 
 -----
 0 1 2  <-- index
 =====
[1]6 9  (i=0; j=0)
[1 6]9  (i=0; j=1)
[1 6 9] (i=0; j=2)
 1[6]9  (i=1; j=1)
 1[6 9] (i=1; j=2)
 1 6[9] (i=2; j=2)
```

Comment: It works very simple :) but actually i dont want `result` as `SortedSet`. If you remove this one, then it is perfect!

Answer (score 4):

Run this in the Groovy console

```
def number = 169
number = number.toString() as List

def results = []

0.upto(number.size()) {numDigits ->

  for(int startPos = 0; startPos + numDigits < number.size(); startPos++) {
    def result = number[startPos..startPos + numDigits]
    results << result.join().toInteger()
  }
}

assert results == [1, 6, 9, 16, 69, 169]
```

Comment: @tim_yates thanks, it gives me great pleasure to finally get one up on you :)

Comment: @Don ;-)  And the assert is probably comparing a List of Strings vs a List of Integers...  Plus, I [added to my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372262/groovy-sequence-of-a-number/6372489#6372489) to show a groovy-er version of your algorithm ;-)  Couldn't resist...sorry

Comment: I'm not sure how groovy does references but if you compare two lists in other java environments, you aren't comparing the values in the lists, you are comparing their memory addresses, which would not be equal.  To compare two lists, you have to compare them element by element.

Comment: @tim_yates you were absolutely right, I've updated the code so it returns a `List<Integer>` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Taking [Don's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372262/groovy-sequence-of-a-number/6372548#6372548) (which works perfectly), I came up with a slightly Groovy-er version of the same thing:

```
def number = 181

number = number.toString() as List

def results = (0..<number.size()).inject([]) { res, numDigits ->
  res.addAll( (0..<number.size()-numDigits).collect { startPos ->
    number[startPos..startPos + numDigits].join() as int
  } )
  res
}

println results
```

Comment: There is problem with 1444 :D

Comment: @Ant yeah, there was a problem with repeat numbers in my original code...  Changed to be a slightly Groovy-er version of Dons really good answer now

Comment: can you explain what it does! i'm an novice in Groovy :D

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to go from Integer to String to List and then back to String with join(), as String already behaves quite like any *sequence*:

```
// Sorry for the silly name. Couldn't think of anything better :)
def subInts(num) {
    def str = num as String
    (1..str.length()).inject([]) { res, size ->
        res += (0..str.length() - size).collect { i -> str[i..< i + size] as int }
    }
}

assert subInts(169) == [1, 6, 9, 16, 69, 169]
```

Aside from having a little less conversions, this is a copy of [tim_yates solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372262/groovy-sequence-of-a-number/6372489#6372489). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

STrictly algorithmically...
You could do something like this:

```
num = 169
ar = []

while ( num >= 1 ) {
    str = num.toString()
    ar.add(str[str.indexOf('.')-1])
    num = num/10.toInteger()
}

len = ar.size()
for ( i in 1..len-1 ) {
    for (j in 0..len-i-1) {
        str = ""
        for ( k in 0..i) {
           str += ar.get(j+k)
        }
        ar.add(str)
    }
}
```

I think that should work.

Answer (score -1):

oneliner

```
(0..<n.size()).inject([]) {a,b -> (0..<n.size()-b).each {a << (n[it] as Integer)};a}
```